# Is there a free VPN service that works on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, vpn

I use Hotspot Shield (Free VPN) on the Windows. Do anyone know of a similar tool or service for Ubuntu?

that:

- Would not require me to have any server.
- would hide my IP.
- Would effectively tunnel all my connections in Ubuntu.
- have free plans

please explain pros and cons of your suggestions.

Answer (score 15):

[VPN One Click](http://www.vpnoneclick.com/) is free (for one year) for Linux, Windows and Android.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Worked like a charm, but needs OpenVPN as well.

Comment: @K-Gun How to configure OpenVPN at this case?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't support Linux any longer

Comment: Still not supporting linux

Answer (score 11):

**Free VPN Connect for Linux**
I just created script for automatic instant free OpenVPN connections to multiple free VPN services.

You can download it on [GitHub](https://github.com/sbandur84/Free-VPN-Connect-for-Linux/releases).

**Supported free services:**
www.vpnbook.com
www.freevpn.me
www.vpnkeys.com

Script is automatic and takes all advertising money from service providers for not visiting their web pages, so plese donate.

**EDIT:** You must be administrator to establish connection to VPN

Comment: New link to github: https://github.com/sbandur84/Free-OpenVPN-Connect-for-Linux

Comment: NEW LINK: https://github.com/sbandur84/Free-OpenVPN-Connect-SCRIPT-for-Linux

Answer (score 4):

There are many (free and paid) different VPN services with Linux support:

- [HideIpVPN](http://www.hideipvpn.com/free-vpn/)
- [USAIP](http://www.usaip.eu/en/free_vpn.php)
- [ItsHidden](http://itshidden.eu/index.php%3Foption%3Dcom_content%26view%3Darticle%26id%3D49%26Itemid%3D27)

[How to install](http://ubuntu-chronicles.blogspot.com/2009/12/karmic-vpn-itshiddencom.html) ItsHidden.

Alternatively you can install *OpenVPN* server on your home PC and use it as a gateway.

If you only need IP anonymity and don't mind of VPN you can also try [TOR](http://www.torproject.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Based on their web site, Hotspot Shield is not a VPN but just a web proxy service that you connect to with HTTPS:

```
Hotspot Shield protects your identity by ensuring that all web transactions
(shopping, filling out forms, downloads) are secured through HTTPS.
```

It should be possible to connect to it from Ubuntu too, but maybe you'll have to configure things manually (e.g. if you need SSL certificates).  You might want to contact them about that.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, openvpn is NOT the answer, nor is any proxy server - because the QUESTION is about free vpn "services", not free vpn "servers" (huge difference!), nor proxy servers (even bigger difference).

The only free VPN service that works on Ubuntu is cyberghost.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this website to configure the PPTP that's built in on Linux 
http://www.freecanadavpn.com/

I have tested it and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

VpnReactor works pretty well https://www.vpnreactor.com/ and has nice free plan.

There is a [tutorial](https://www.vpnreactor.com/linux_openvpn.html) how to install it on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu provides openvpn as a package that can be used to create virtual private networks between different computers over a public network.

Comment: How to utilize it?