# How to setup IPsec effectively ** Whats the use of xl2tpd?

Tags: 11.04, vpn

How to setup IPSec effectively on LAN so that I can securely use from a machine of different external network.

Whats the significance of `xl2tpd`. 
I see that IPSec is faster than OpenVPN.

Also I would like to know if something like `Hotspot Shield` can be implemented LAN, where they assign a different IP address on after establishing secure VPN.

** I see the fact that HotSpot Shield Server are located in USA.

> ---
>
> ```
>  **IPSec is a kernel implementation while OpenVPN is a userspace 
>    implementation
> ```
>
> ---

Comment: Since posting the question have you found a solution or do you still require help?

Answer (score 2):

You have three separate questions here - Ask Ubuntu works best on single question and answers.

I recommend you have a read through the [Man Page for ipsec](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man5/ipsec.conf.5.html). It should give you a good overview of the package and how it works.

I have no experience on setting up what you want to achieve but I was able to find [this guide](http://rootmanager.com/ubuntu-ipsec-l2tp-windows-domain-auth/setting-up-openswan-xl2tpd-with-native-windows-clients-lucid.html) to set it up on 10.04, it still should be fairly relevant to 11.04 though. It details `xl2tpd` Since Windows default client is more than just IPSec, it uses L2TP inside of an IPSec SA, you need a daemon to handle that which is what `xl2tpd` will do.

As for Hotspot Shield have a read through a [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6853/is-there-a-free-service-like-hotspot-shield-for-ubuntu) for information on it and details on other options.